# Ambiguous tab completion not working in iPython on Windows

Tags: python, ipython, tab-completion

I am running IPython on Windows 7 x64 with pyreadline installed.  If I start a new session and type:

```
import numpy
nu<TAB>
```

Then `nu` autocompletes to `numpy`.  However, if I start a new session and try this:

```
import numpy
n<TAB>
```

Then nothing happens.  I would expect it to cycle through all of the possible completions.  I'm currently using out of the box config, do I need to change a setting to enable ambiguous tab completion or am I just out of luck?

**EDIT**:
To address the comment from ma3204, here is another example (start with fresh ipython session):

```
[In 1]: value1 = 5

[In 2]: value2 = 6

[In 3]: va<TAB>       ... nothing happens
[In 3]: va<Ctrl + l>
vars   value2 value1

[In 3]: val<TAB>      ... completes to 'value'
[In 3]: value
[In 3]: value<Ctrl + l>
value2 value1

[In 3]: value
```

When I type `va<TAB>` above I would expect each tab press to cycle through `value1`, `value2`, `vars`, `value1`, `value2`, etc.

Comment: I'm running the same issue. Windows 7 x64 here. It used to work fine in Vista x86.

Comment: I just tried this with Win7x64, with a few other packages (other than numpy) and it worked fine (with 2+ separate sessions). Maybe it's a numpy-specific issue?

Comment: I had the same problem, same environment, Python, etc but without numpy installed. So it's clearly not an issue with that package. Could be some weirdness with the pyreadline or iPython configuration files (I can't work it out).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to copy config file for pyreadline to your HOME folder (C:\Users\< username >).

Open Command line and execute that:

```
copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline\configuration\pyreadlineconfig.ini" %HOMEPATH%
```

Comment: Awesome.  I had given up on getting this to work and had resigned myself to Slasher's workaround.

Comment: Thank god, how did you come up with this solution?

Comment: One detail: if you have an HOME variable defined the .ini must go there instead of %HOMEPATH%

Comment: It works!  My path was `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyreadline\configuration`, though.

Answer (score 6):

Just installed python 2.6 and numpy, ipython and so on. I am also annoyed of this. On my other computers with older installations it works. I use the completions list very much to see what commands are available so I feel frustrated when it doesn't work.

EDIT: Found that you can get it with CTRL-l. Looked in ipythonrc and it should work like I am used to but not. The CTRL-l work though. Will see if it kicks back on. Seem to remember that I had similar trouble before but it worked after some time.

Comment: +1 That's better than nothing.  Thanks for the tip.  For others who find this page, please note that the shortcut key is `Ctrl + <lowercase L>` not `Ctrl + <uppercase I>`.  It took me a few minutes to realize that.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now, since it seems ipython does not currently support this feature in this environment.  If someone knows differently, please add it as an answer and I'll update my marked answer as appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did differently, but I never experienced this issue with the same OS, software, etc. Tab completion worked as expected for me.

Comment: Oh my, thanks so much!  This was driving me nuts having just switched to Windows for my main dev environment I really missed my iPython completion lists!

Comment: See Luka's answer for the approved solution.