# Weird behaviour of pyreadline autocompletion with cmd module in Python on Windows

Tags: python, autocomplete, cmd, readline

I'm trying to run this simple code with:

- Python 2.7.2
- Windows 7
- pyreadline installed from pip

  ```
  class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
      """Simple command processor example."""

      FRIENDS = [ 'Alice', 'Adam', 'Barbara', 'Bob', 'Chris' ]

      def do_greet(self, person):
          "Greet the person"
          if person and person in self.FRIENDS:
              greeting = 'hi, %s!' % person
          elif person:
              greeting = "hello, " + person
          else:
              greeting = 'hello'
          print greeting

      def complete_greet(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
          if not text:
              completions = self.FRIENDS[:]
          else:
              completions = [ f
                              for f in self.FRIENDS
                              if f.startswith(text)
                              ]
          return completions

      def do_EOF(self, line):
          return True

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      HelloWorld().cmdloop()
  ```

It seems the autocompletion does not work. When I run it and I type:

```
(Cmd) greet A<tab>
```

It gives no autocompletion suggestions but it should give "Alice Adam".

However, when I type:

```
(Cmd) greet C<tab>
```

It rightfully autocomplete with 'Chris'. So it seems related with whether or not there is more than one match for the autocompletion.

Does anybody have an explanation or know how to fix this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Removed leftover phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out. The file pyreadlineconfig.ini was located in the wrong directory.

I followed the fix in [Ambiguous tab completion not working in iPython on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771837/ambiguous-tab-completion-not-working-in-ipython-on-windows)

which says to copy this file to %HOMEPATH%. Turns out this environment variable is misconfigured on my PC and the file was copied to e:\pyreadlineconfig.ini.

The right path but should instead be c:\users\username.