# pyreadline configuration through script

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is similar to [Ambiguous tab completion not working in iPython on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771837/ambiguous-tab-completion-not-working-in-ipython-on-windows/4126854) which is resolved by solution of copying a pyreadline config file to user's HOME directory.

While this solution works, it seems hacky. I want to be able to do this pyreadline configuration from my script. I tried to directly call read_inputrc method on pyreadline and passing a temporary config file but it doesn't seem available. So is there any possible programmatic way to allow ambiguous tab completion in pyreadline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the correct answer, but i was able to get it working by doing this-

```
from readline import rl as readline
readline.mode.show_all_if_ambiguous("on")
```

Basically readline.py has a Readline class instance rl which has a 'mode' property which i am modifying. Essentially the config file does the same. But this solution has convenience of doing it in the script itself.